# Fading Edge on Android WebView doesn't load - unless I'm missing something?

Tags: android, android-webview, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have an activity which is basically just a WebView which loads some inline HTML and when the user scrolls I want the edges to fade. I know this isn't complicated, and I have it working on a bunch of other activities with ListViews and so on, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Here is the XML for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/browser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. I'm open to all (constructive) ideas.

Oh, and I also set `((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview)).setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);` programmatically right now too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd, but, here's what solved my issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/browser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent" />

</ScrollView>
```